# execute Python3 file with Sudo using PHP

Tags: python, php, sudo

hey guy how can i sudo execute a python3 script with PHP? i tried:

```
exec("sudo -E python3 /var/www/html/send.py " . $_POST['username'] . " " . $_POST['msg']);
```

that should execute this:

```
sudo -E python3 /var/www/html/send.py TheUsername TheMessageIinputed
```

if i executed this comand in the terminal it works but here it doesnt work...

I also put this into sudoers script:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

but still doesnt work...

Comment: & what when someone's username is `; some nasty command script`? use the correct escaping!

Comment: Why not make your python script runnable by www-data? Much safer, though you still need to escape your user input as @Jaquarh suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know what you are doing, because it is absolutely nuts. And I hope your machine is in a localnet where you are the only person who has access.

Anyway, You can try this if you want to see what is going on:

```php
$user = $_POST['username'];
$msg  = $_POST['msg'];

$exec = "sudo -E python3 /var/www/html/send.py $user $msg 2>&1"
exec($exec, $output, $return);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return);
```